# Minesweeper recreation in html css and js doesn't count right the neighboring bomb cells

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recreate minesweeper in html,css and javascript and I got to the part where I need to check the neighboring cells to see if it is a bomb and count it, but it doesn`t seem to check the right cells. I am using a cell class with an x, y, isBomb, isChecked and a number for how many of its neighbors is a bomb, also I am using a 1D array to store the grid of cells
So my question is if it is something wrong with this function or should I just rewrite the code using a 2D array insted

```
function checkN(x, y){
    let count = 0

    if(cells[x+y*coll].isBomb == true){
        return
    }

    cells[x+y*coll].isChecked = true

    for(let i = -1; i<=1; i++)
        for(let j = -1; j<=1; j++){
            if(
                (x+i >= 0 && x+i < coll) &&
                (y+j >= 0 && y+j < rows) &&
                (i != 0 || j != 0)
            ){
                if(cells[x+i + (y+j)*rows].isBomb == true)
                    count++
            }
        }
    
    if(count != 0)
        cells[x + y*coll].number = count
}
```

[result of using the checkN function for every cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ7Xv.png)

I have tried changing the values a bit, like add an -1 there add an +1 there, but still it doesn`t count right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is mixing `coll` and `rows`:

```js
                if(cells[x+i + (y+j)*rows].isBomb == true)
                //                   ^^^^

...

    cells[x + y*coll].number = count
    //          ^^^^
```

Sometimes you access the cell at `x, y` as `cells[x + y*coll]`, and sometimes as `cells[x + y*rows]`. I think the `coll` one is correct (every `y` skips a full row, which is made of `coll` columns), so try changing your code to:

```js
if(cells[x+i + (y+j)*colls].isBomb == true)
//                   ^^^^^ changed here
```

And consider extracting this bit of logic into its own function, so you don't make this mistake anymore.

*(the `== true` part is also redundant, as is having one `if` inside another, but neither should cause problems)*

Comment: Well that fixed it, thank you very much, I really didn’t see that I have put rows instead of Coll. Thank you again